# Would an exponential lower bound on an NP-complete language prove P does not equal NP?

Tags: time-complexity, theory, exponential, np, p-np

If someone were able to prove an exponential lower bound for a NP-complete problem, would that prove that P ≠ NP?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would prove that P is not equal to NP. All polynomials are bounded from above by any exponential function, so an exponential lower bound on *any* NP problem would prove that the problem is not in P, and thus would prove that P cannot equal NP.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right.
If you prove an exponential lower bound for A, you have shown that A cannot lie in P. If A did lie in P, it would be decidable in polynomial time which is asymptotically faster than your just proven lower bound - we have a contradiction!

However, you don't have to pick an NP-complete problem. You can pick any language A in NP. By proving that A does not lie in P, you have also proven that P does not equal NP. Why? Because if P did equal NP, A would also lie in P, since we just picked A from NP.